# what is the value of angle A

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

The [triangle ABC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zogRb.jpg) is random. The line $AD$ is twice big as the line $DC$ ($AD=2*DC$). We know only the two angles that are shown in the picture. What's the value of angle $A$?

Comment: Angle BDC is 120° and so you can calculate side BD from triangle BCD. From there you can calculate angle A Just some Laws of sines formulas. (Set CD=1)

Comment: @imranfat can you write for me?

Comment: @imranfat i mean the sines law. Because i tried and i failed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In triangle BDC you can set up the Sine Law: $\frac{DC}{\sin15^{\circ}}=\frac{BD}{\sin45^{\circ}}$ with $DC=1$, I get $BD=2.732$ Now in triangle BDA we will have to use the Law of Cosine because you have 2 sides with an enclosed angle D so calculating AB we get $AB²=2.732²+2²-2*2.732*2*\cos60°$ which gives $AB=\sqrt{6}$. Now apply Law of Sines in triangle BDA to calculate A. You got three sides and an angle. please give it a try

Comment: You got something wrong, the angle DBC isn't 75 degrees its 15 degrees. Because ADC is 60 so BDC is 120 degrees

Comment: You are right. I think I fixed it (rather quick)

Comment: Hmmm, strange. I got a down vote without a reason....Feels like someone rings my doorbell and runs away before I open...

Comment: If someone marked down for an error (that is easily repaired) think how it feels to get a down vote for technically correct answers (have seen a few).

Comment: @jim Yes, that is indeed very true. But I got a downvote AFTER my fix and my answer was already accepted. How is that? I think in general one should be required to reveal his/her identity if one should put forward a downvote. If I vote to close a question (sometimes I do that), my vote gets recorded and can be seen by everyone...Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @imranfat As I've mentioned in previous posts elsewhere, I've never understood why technically correct answers are down voted.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the measure of the angle (and after deduce with a geometric/trigonometric procedure) Geogebra gives the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

assumption $\overline{CD}=1$
point C $(-1\mid 0)$
point D $(0\mid 0)$
point A $(2\mid 0)$
point B $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3}2\mid\frac{3+\sqrt3}2\right)\quad$ intersection of
$\qquad\qquad y=x\tan {60°}$ and $y=(x+1)\tan{45°}$
angle A =$\tan^{-1}{\frac{\frac{3+\sqrt3}2}{\frac{1+\sqrt3}2-2}}$
=$\tan^{-1}(2+\sqrt3)=75°$

Answer (score 0):

In the figure below we have $$\frac ac=\frac{\sin x}{\sin 45^\circ}\qquad(1)$$ Furthermore
$$\frac{z}{\sin 15^\circ}=\frac{a}{\sin 120^\circ}\qquad(2)$$
$$\frac{2z}{\sin (120^\circ-x)}=\frac{c}{\sin 60^\circ}\qquad(3)$$

From $(1),(2),(3)$ we get $$1.46407\sin x=1.7320\cos x+\sin x\iff \tan x=3.73219$$

Thus $$\color{red}{x\approx 75.00053^\circ}$$
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct is answer equal to $75°$

I did it by construction

First of all I made triangle $BDC$ with ur provided information and doing some calculations ie ($\measuredangle DBC=15°$, $\measuredangle BDC=120^{\circ}$ ,$\measuredangle BCD=45°$) than I continued line $CD$ till point $A$ with ur information ($2CD=AD$) as I got point $A$ , I joined it with $B$ and calculated $\measuredangle BAD$ which comes up to be $75°$

Comment: If you are going to answer please explain how you got to it.

Comment: Well I did it by construction! And found angle to be exactly equal to $70°$

Comment: Can you explain that in your answer?

Comment: The answer is 75 but i think 70 is be correct too

Comment: Can you tell me how you got to 70 because i think thats correct

Comment: I am sorry! I am not my having laptop right now

Comment: Wait for a sec I tell u

Comment: @sanketalekar i didnt get to 75. I just know the answer. So can you explain how you did it?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question,

Comment: Believe me or not,now it is coming 75°

Comment: I have provided more detailed information in answer.  (Not the correct way to proceed)